# php preg replace same string multiple times in a long string

Tags: php, preg-replace, match

I have a long string

```
$str = "#10:19.out.#7:970.in.#8:19.out.#7:3128.in.#10:101.out.#7:3131.in.#15:19.out.#7:170917.in.#10:4517.out.#7:170909.in.#12:17593"
```

If I use pattern

```
$pattern = "/out\..*in/"
$replacement = "";
$path = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
```

Then the output is `#10:19..#12:17593`

Which is the longest match of my pattern.

I want to replace each match in the string, and get result like

```
#10:19.#8:19.#10:101.#15:19.#10:4517.#12:17593
```

Could anyone help me to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Make the quantifier ungreedy. Add a `?` immediately after the `*`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "#10:19.out.#7:970.in.#8:19.out.#7:3128.in.#10:101.out.#7:3131.in.#15:19.out.#7:170917.in.#10:4517.out.#7:170909.in.#12:17593";

$pattern = "/out\..*?in./";
$replacement = "";
$path = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
```